# How python variables name in getter and setter method are different to the name in its constructor?

Tags: python, properties

I am confused to a example of property from python cookbook.

```
class Person:
     def __init__(self, first_name):
          self.first_name = first_name
     @property
     def first_name(self): 
          return self._first_name
     @first_name.setter
     def first_name(self, value): 
          self._first_name = value
>>>people = Person('Tom')
>>>people.first_name
'Tom'
>>>people.first_name = 'Jack'
>>>people.first_name
'Jack'
```

When a instance is created, a argument assigns to self.first_name. However, it will return a value of self._first_name when getter property is called since self.first_name is distinguish to self._first_name. What is a relationship between self.first_name and self._first_name? How the two different variables related to each other?

Comment: `first_name` is a property, `_first_name` is an attribute.

Comment: The code doesn't look valid. `self.first_name = name`, `name` is undefined, but even if it were `self.first_name = first_name`, it would replace the property definitions.

Comment: `>>> people._first_name` is invalid.

Comment: @Peter How is it "invalid", where is it used?

Comment: `_first_name` is never set.

Comment: @Peter You said that the self._first_name is property. Do you mean the self._first_name called in constructor is the method below __init__()?

Comment: @pipi I don't understand. I didn't say `self._first_name` is a property.

Answer (score 1):

`self.first_name`/`people.first_name` is the setter method-turned-property `def first_name(self, value)`, while `self._first_name` is the actual attribute holding the value. The constructor uses the setter to set the initial name, it doesn't directly assign to the property.

1. constructor receives value as function parameter
2. constructor assigns to property `first_name` which
3. invokes the setter `def first_name` which
4. assigns to the property `_first_name`

Note that there's another confusing typo in the constructor, it should be `self.first_name = first_name`.

Comment: No, `self.first_name = first_name` wipes out the property and `_first_name` never gets set.

Comment: If `Person` derives from `object` in 2.7 then it also works. Classes derive from `object` automatically in 3.0