# Setter doesn't fire when setting property inside init

Tags: python

How do i fix this so the 'setter' event fires when i init a new TreeNode and pass it the attribute node?

```
class TreeNode( QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem ):
    def __init__( self, parent, node ):
        super( TreeNode, self ).__init__( parent )
        self._node_object = node

    @property
    def node_object(self):
        return self._node_object

    @node_object.setter
    def node_object(self, value):
        self._node_object = value
        self.setText( 0, self._node_object.name )
        print "set data"
```

This will not fire the setter event.

```
node_object = Faction("Doug")
tree_node = TreeNode(self.node_tree, node_object)
```

However this will fire the event... but ideally i wanted to directly pass the Node to the TreeNode.

```
node_object = Faction("Doug")
tree_node = TreeNode(self.node_tree, None)
tree_node.node_object = node_object
```

---

UPDATED

Is this the proper way of setting it up then?

```
class TreeNode( QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem ):
    def __init__( self, parent, node ):
        super( TreeNode, self ).__init__( parent )
        self.node_object = node

    @property
    def node_object(self):
        return self._node_object

    @node_object.setter
    def node_object(self, value):
        self._node_object = value
        self.setText( 0, self._node_object.name )
        print "set data"
```

Comment: Updated code looks fine

Comment: thank you. i appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're circumventing the setter by directly assigning to the underlying property. If you want to invoke the setter, **assign to the setter**:

```
self.node_object = node
```

Comment: see the updated section above, is that the proper way of setting it up then?

Comment: Test it. Does it work? Then yes. (Note that the behaviour *may* be different in Python 2 with old-style classes, which is unclear from the question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34025613/how-python-variables-name-in-getter-and-setter-method-are-different-to-the-name/34025675?noredirect=1#comment55928082_34025675)

Comment: If `QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem` is not a new-style class, you can ensure that `TreeNode` is by adding `object` to the list of base classes. Given the code you show, that should work without introducing any other problems.